# Android Studio : How to Cast to View UI like as Eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse, 
The below code:

```
ListView lv = view.findViewById(R.id.my_lv);
```

It will be show a red line at view.findViewById(R.id.my_lv). When moving the mouse in it, it will show "Add Cast to ListView". When clicking "Add Cast to ListView", it will import automatically, like that.

```
ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_lv);
```

How can to do it on Android Studio?

Comment: coding doesn't change with IDE.

Comment: The question was clear please remove your suggestions for closing the question @Kampai 2Dee Mohamad jbutler JiTHiN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click and hover your mouse to the red line, and click the red bulb button, click `Cast to 'android.widget.ListView'`

OR

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: First step]

[image: Second Step]

Answer (score 0):

To Auto `import` in **Android studio** you have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>  which ask for each thing, and I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept it.

For Auto `import` you can go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java` and make the changes as:

change `Insert imports on paste value` to All

mark `Add unambigious imports on the fly` option as selected

Comment: Thanks u, but it only imports in auto, not help me "Cast to". Your help like Ctrl shift 0 in eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

Write like below:

//If you are getting ListView directly from main xml then write like below:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_lv);
```

//If you getting your list view from sub xml after inflating any other xml or from header xml then write like below way:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)YOUR INFLATED VIEW.findViewById(R.id.my_lv);
```

//You directly can remove this error by IDE options.

Just do mouse hover on red line and press **alt+enter**, it will automatically do casting for the same.